# How do i repeat these pyautogui.click() functions in Python?

Tags: python

I have some code like:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(100, 100)
pyautogui.click(30, 20)
pyautogui.click(70, 500)
pyautogui.click(50, 10)
```

how can I make it so that the clicks are repeated?

Comment: "but it didnt work." Please show the actual code you tried and give the error message that you got. Better yet, google the error message to find potential solutions for the problem.

Comment: this is what comes in the vs code console: File "path", line 4
    pyautogui.click(100, 100)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: This error means that you have some problem on the code formattings. Check you spaces/tabs also check [how to indent](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html)

Answer (score 0):

yes thanks @Carlo Zanocco, the problem was that i had to tab after the loop statement:

```
import pyautogui
c = True
while c:
    pyautogui.click(100, 100)
    pyautogui.click(30, 20)
    pyautogui.click(70, 500)
    pyautogui.click(50, 10)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suggest you read the official Python tutorial at python.org. It will explain these required details.